# Is there something wrong with my question regarding Outlook?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

I asked a question [Outlook 2013 gives Windows Security warning when adding live account](https://superuser.com/questions/805863/outlook-2013-gives-windows-security-warning-when-adding-live-account?noredirect=1#comment1052481_805863) on the website and only got a downvote. I am not sure why.

Can anyone explain whether my question has some problem?

I did google for many days, checked multiple Microsft support articles, various other websites and it's not a question where I just forgot to click a button or something but an actual issue in Outlook 2013. So what's the thing that I missed in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your biggest problem seems to be that you aren't waiting long enough. You only asked the question yesterday. One downvote doesn't mean your question is terrible, just that one person didn't like it.

This may be an unusual or fringe issue where there is no easy fix or obvious thing you're doing wrong, so most people who see it might just skip by it.

Comment: Just wanted to be sure. My previous questions on superuser had bad history. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AseemBansal - I only see a single downvote for all 5 of your questions.  You do understand questions that are deleted count more against a question ban.  The best way to avoid one is to ask well researched questions that are complete and percise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your question.  I don't see any need for a downvote.

At the time of writing it has only 10 views, maybe you just need to be more patient - wait for the right people to see it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the same.